# What are the practical differences between AC and DC transmission?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, wire, power-engineering

I have a long (2m) but thick wire between transformer-based power supply and low frequency power amplifier. Know your best advice ahead, but no, I cant get rid of it.

I can put it in two configurations:

[image]

What should I choose and why?

---

Looking at some transformer-based PSU's like for mixer equipement I can see a long wire with AC, plus a bridge right in a mixer, but not in the PSU. But looking at SMPS especially for notebooks - they are mostly shielded cables, but runs DC - shottky bridges are close to transformer.

Comment: The thing about transformer AC powersupplies is in many locations they are only allowed to be sold for devices that require AC to operate. so if the maker wants to aviod using a switched-mode powersupply it helps to require the device to use AC for operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LONG leads between the transformer and the rectifier, lots of EMI will be generated and radiated, as the diodes in the rectifier turn on quickly (microseconds, if not faster) and the rapid change in current thru the long-wires provides external magnetic fields that are very difficult to shield with just copper foil.

And place small capacitors (100uF) right by the rectifier.

Something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGrQD2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Great, just the opposite answer :-) so you think better is to set up (I have full bridge) just nearby transformer?

Comment: Larger capacitor is of no worry, they said. So I thought for inductor. To "localize a field" one day i put a whole transformer secondary (thinking it is a great inductor). Tda2050 welded inside, and current found its path through its case to the tab, melting it in bright orange color dot.

Comment: Suppose your power amplifier uses 10amps, or 100 amps peak thru the rectifiers, and the diodes turn on in 1uSecond. We'll assume the power transformer permits that speed of turnon. Thus the dI/dT is 100amp/1uS or 10^+8 amps per second. Assume your power cable is placed 10cm from the vinyl-record playback turntable, with 1milliVolt signal at strong audio output. We want 80dB SNR, thus need 100 nanoVolts interference level, or smaller. Assume the vinyl RIAA preamp has 1cm by 10cm PCB loop. Interference will be computed from Vinduce (magnetic field) is MUo * MUr * Area/Distance * dI/dT.

Comment: That formula simplifies, using MUo as 4*pi*1e-7, MUr as air or copper = 1, to Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT. We have all the numbers. What is Vinduce? 2e-7 * (Area = 1cm * 10cm) / (Distance = 10cm) * dI/dT = 1e+8. We now have 2e-7 H/meter * 1cm * 1e+8 = 2e-9 * 1e+8 = 0.2 volts. Yet our budget is 100 nanoVolts. People over in diyAudio.com develop not only 1milliVolt vinyl-playback systems (moving magnet) but 100 uV systems for moving-coils. Their trash-budget is ~~ a nanoVolt of Hum, etc. How to do this? They have 1 meter spacing between XFORM/Diodes and the low-noise circuits.

Comment: Another detail is to SLOW DOWN the turnon time of the diodes, with small resistors or small inductors in series, People often place 1nF capacitors in parallel with each diode, for the same reason.

Comment: Got you, in simple words you are telling that transferring high-current AC over long cable would emit strong EMI, strong enough to catch mains HUM by sensitive low-noise circuits. I've heard how does video card on mining process produces noise, with amplified dynmamic microphone coil at about meter apart from motherboard. GPU is usually powered with multiple short (60cm) low voltage (12v) high current(25a) wires, coming to PCIe molex power connectors.

Comment: But what about "twisted pair"? First of all i use dual power supply. What is better in a case of dual DC supply? Is it "1 bridge, 3 wires" (shielded twisted pair with a common ground wire). Or "2 bridges 4-wires", that will require 2x full bridge rectifiers and two twisted pairs, (but probably does not require a shielding)? What should be "twist step"?

Comment: If you don't use a moving coil as your input signal source, I'd not worry. The "1 bridge, 3 wires " should be fine, because YOU WILL HAVE 100UF CAPACITORS on +out and on -out of the bridge. That helps keep the fast transient currents in the remote box.

Comment: people at diyaudiio.com often seek 1 nanovolt interference. is that your goal?

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter for your use case.

I'd still go with putting the rectifier behind the cable, because it leaves you with better maintenance options, e.g. if you want to insert a switch or relay into that cable later.

Comment: So will I do. Just curious about possible diffirences. Is it significantly worse to switch a DC?

Comment: @xakepp35, yes, [switching DC is somewhat harder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156901/switch-current-rating-ac-vs-dc).

Comment: And there's always the possibility of getting the polarity wrong when repairing or replacing wiring with DC. Explaining a repair or replacement to someone else is also harder with DC.  AC is just less worry.

Comment: DC systems are fine - just pay attention : having trained as an auto-electrician I have seen some excellent errors and consequences by people who start with "but I thought it worked like this... "...

Comment: @SolarMike swapping polarity for tda2050 or 7294 power legs, as well as for large electrolytic caps are my favorite stuff to do . I love fireworks :-)

Comment: @xakepp35 charging caps and throwing them to have others catch them... but H&S so we never did that ,never...

Comment: @SolarMike jokes apart. If the only "pros" of AC are their easier switching and polarity independence I should select DC variant